# Laravel Vuejs API Login Validation

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

I am trying to validate my API Login controller with Vuejs using Vform
But it does not display the error on client side

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
class SignInController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        if (!$token = auth()->attempt($request->only('email', 'password'))) {
            return response(null, 401);
        }

        return response()->json([], 401);

    }
}
```

Below is the Method i am using with Vuejs and i do not know why the validation is not working at all.

```
methods: {
      ...mapActions({
        signIn: 'auth/signIn',
      }),

      submit () {
        this.$Progress.start();
        this.signIn(this.form) 
        .then(()=>{
          this.form.reset()
          window.$('#autoLogin').modal('hide')
          if(this.$route.path !=='/')
          this.$router.push('/')
          this.$Progress.finish();
        })
        .catch(()=>{

        })

      },
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do the errors display if you submit the form without providing an email or password? When validate fails it returns a structured json object, but your other two failure return points don't return the same json structure.

Comment: @coedycode it does not display error with empty email or password. but i can see the error in json format under (Network Preview). What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like vform should work with laravels validate error formatting out of the box https://github.com/cretueusebiu/vform. Could you show your vue form please?

Comment: @coedycode i am using that but still it won't show error on client side

Comment: It sounds like the problem is in your client side template or login method, if you can show those here it might help debug the problem.

Comment: @coedycode i have updated it with the method

Comment: I think it might be because you're passing 'this.form' to a vuex action, have you tried doing the this.form.post in your vue component instead?

Comment: @coedycode did that, and it did not work ```this.form.post('signIn')```

Comment: @coedycode i was able to get it to work using this ```this.form.post('auth/signin')``` then after i added ```this.signIn(this.form)``` that means it would send two request. is this a good way?

Comment: You haven't shown your signIn action so it's hard to say. You can probably modify that action so that it doesn't need this.form anymore, or simply call a vuex mutation from your component's this.form.post('auth/signin').then